# Listbox does not compute previous added data along with the latest added data item

Tags: vb.net

I am currently working with this automated application using VB.net in visua studio. I am using data datagridview then add to cart button to move the added data to the listbox. Now, I am currently trying to compute the added item but the problem is that it only computes the latest added item instead of all the added items. I have attached the picture so that you can understand more the problem I am encountering.

[image]

I need the listbox where if I click the save sales invoice button, it also computes the previous added item along with the latest added item.

```
Private Sub compute()
    Dim itemname As String
    Dim labor, itemprice, quantity, total, priceperquantity As Double

    FrmSummary.LstOrder.Items.Clear()

    If IsNumeric(Guna2TextBox3.Text) And IsNumeric(Guna2TextBox2.Text) And Guna2TextBox1.Text <> "" And txtLabor.Text <> "" Then
        itemname = Guna2TextBox1.Text
        itemprice = CDbl(Guna2TextBox2.Text)
        labor = CDbl(txtLabor.Text)
        quantity = CDbl(Guna2TextBox3.Text)


        Dim laborCost As Double = labor
        Dim partsCost As Double = itemprice
        Dim quantity1 As Double = quantity
        Dim itemperquantity As Double = priceperquantity

        itemperquantity = (itemprice * quantity)

        total = laborCost + itemperquantity

        FrmSummary.LstOrder.Items.Add("Item Name: " & (itemname))
        FrmSummary.LstOrder.Items.Add("Item Price: " & (itemprice))
        FrmSummary.LstOrder.Items.Add("Quantity: " & (quantity))
        FrmSummary.LstOrder.Items.Add("Labor Cost: " & FormatCurrency(laborCost))
        FrmSummary.LstOrder.Items.Add("Total: " & FormatCurrency(total))

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid input!")

    End If

End Sub


Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    If Guna2TextBox1.Text <> "" And Guna2TextBox2.Text And Guna2TextBox3.Text <> "" Then
        compute()
        FrmSummary.ShowDialog()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: A `ListBox` doesn't compute anything. Your code does that, but you haven't shown us any code so we have no idea what might be wrong with it. Post the relevant code and also explain exactly what and where it behaves other than as you expect. If you haven't actually debugged the code yet and can't give us that information then it's too soon to be asking a question here. If you don't know how to debug, you need to stop what you're doing and learn first, because you always need to provide us with debugging information.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to post the Code. My bad

Comment: I need a code where it also computes the previous added item along with the latest added item

Comment: What does that mean? What EXACTLY are you expecting to happen that doesn't happen or what happens that you aren't expecting? You need to provide specific details including what happens when you debug and how and where that differs from your expectations. Again, you need to actually debug the code. If you don't know how, learn first, then do it, then update the question.

Comment: I can't help but feel you're kind of making this hard for yourself by dropping everything straight into the list box.  You will be better off when clicking the _Add to Cart_ button, to add your item to an in-memory collection, for example a DataTable or List(of SomeClass) with property's matching what you want to display making calculations easy, then display that collection in your list box.